# Why is React rendering the children in this scenario? (State is the same, using useState)

Tags: reactjs

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-useforceupdate-cizn3?file=/src/App.js)

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const Foo = () => {
  console.log("render foo");
  return <div> foo</div>;
};

const App = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(1);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("effect", value);
  }, [value]);

  console.log("rendering");
  return (
    <div>
      {" "}
      <Foo /> <button onClick={() => setValue(value)}>Click To Render</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Now according to the [React Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#bailing-out-of-a-state-update)

> If you update a State Hook to the same value as the current state, React will bail out **without rendering the children or firing effects**. *(emphasis mine)*
>    (React uses the Object.is comparison algorithm.)
>
> Note that React may still need to render that specific component again before bailing out. That shouldn’t be a concern because React won’t unnecessarily go “deeper” into the tree. If you’re doing expensive calculations while rendering, you can optimize them with useMemo.

In the example I've given, we can see that the useEffect hook doesn't fire, as described by the documentation, but my `Foo` component is rendering.

Why is this?

I thought that maybe the inline function causes a render - but if I change that to a memoized function using `useCallback` the same behaviour happens:

```
  const handleClick = useCallback(() => setValue(value), [value]);

  console.log("rendering");
  return (
    <div>
      {" "}
      <Foo /> <button onClick={handleClick}>Click To Render</button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bail out logic was implemented in v16.8.0 of react-dom in which react also introduced hooks, whereas your demo uses the alpha version of hooks which is why you still see a re-render being triggered even when you update with the same state

> According to [v16.8.0](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1690-august-8-2019) release notes
>
> - Bail out of rendering on identical values for useState and useReducer Hooks. (@acdlite in #14569)

[image: Edit FORM VALUES]

Comment: Ugh. Thanks. Good to know to look out for that.